# Processing all audio outputs on Windows using audio hooking technique

Tags: audio, audio-processing, juce

We aim to enhance our audio DSP application which is written with JUCE Framework by enabling it to process all audio outputs on Windows using audio hooking technique, similar to the functionality provided by the Equalizer APO application. Our goal is to integrate our application into the Windows audio processing pipeline, thereby allowing it to apply audio processing effects to audio output. How can this be done? What are the APIs/libraries that we can use?